# Multiplos stage com javaFX

Tags: javafx

Bom dia, essa pergunta é bem simples mas estou começando com JavaFx e travei em uma questão, por exemplo, classe main com a tela principal onde terá um botão que ao ser clicado irá abrir outro stage. Tenho que ter um controller para cada tela, até ai tranquilo, porém não quero centralizar toda chamada dos stage no main, nesse caso tenho que criar outra classe para o stage secundário?
Está meio confuso pra mim por isso não consegui explicar muito bem.
Já entendi todo conceito de quando é apenas um stage, inclusive faço o layout com FXML pra facilitar.
Caso tenham algum exemplo para me elucidar, ficarei grato.
Grato a todos.

Comment: Oi @Ronaldo Alves. É benéfico para a comunidade dar um retorno se o problema foi resolvido ou se ainda permanece. Deixei uma resposta porém você não deu um retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo utilizar uma classe [Singleton](http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-singleton-em-java/26392) para trabalhar o `Stage`. Assim, para alternar entre telas nos controladores chamo o método `loadNewStage` da minha classe responsável por trabalhar o `Stage`.

**Classe HaveStage**

```
public class HaveStage {

    private static HaveStage haveStage = null;
    private Stage stage;

    private HaveStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public static HaveStage instance(Stage stage) {
        if (haveStage == null) {
            haveStage = new HaveStage(stage);
        }
        return haveStage;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return this.stage;
    }

    public void loadNewStage(Parent fxmlLoad) {
        if (stage != null) {
            Parent root = fxmlLoad;
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            //stage.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe Application**

```
public class MinhaClasse extends Application {
    private HaveStage haveStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.haveStage = HaveStage.instance(stage);
        Parent root = null;
        Scene scene;

        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/br/com/projeto/primeiraTela.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MinhaClasse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        scene = new Scene(root);

        haveStage.getStage().setScene(scene);
        haveStage.getStage().show();
    }
}
```

Sempre que desejar alternar a tela chame o método `loadNewStage` nos controladores.

**Controlador Exemplo**

```
public class LoginScreenController {
    @FXML
    void login(InputEvent event) {
        try {
            Parent temp = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/br/com/projeto/segundaTela.fxml"));
            changeScreen(temp);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
            new Notifications().errorNotification("Erro ao carregar nova tela!");
        }
    }

    private void changeScreen(Parent fxmlLoad) {
        HaveStage.instance(null).loadNewStage(fxmlLoad);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, recentemente criei uma classe utilitária para abstrair a criação de telas no JavaFX, a instalação é simples e o uso também. Basicamente o que deve ser feito é estender seu controller de WindowControllerFx, sobrescrever o método getFXML onde você informa o caminho do seu layout, por fim instanciar a classe e chamar uma das opções de métodos show (show(), showAsDialog()...).

A lib está [aqui](https://github.com/Andrauss/WindowControllerFx)